# jQuery wrap a label with an a href

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="nf-field-label">
     <label for="nf-field-11" id="nf-label-field-11" class="">Terms &amp; Conditions <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span> 
      </label>
</div>
```

I have tried the following however its not appending to the label why?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$("#nf-field-11").wrapInner('<a href="#faq"></a>');
});
```

Comment: You dont seem to have a DOM element with id nf-field-11.

Comment: `<a>` cannot contain interactive elements like `<label>`. That would be invalid HTML.

Comment: You cannot do this as you cannot have a clickable element (ie. an `a`) inside another clickable element (the `label`)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What would the best way be to do what I need (a clickable label)

Comment: You don't need to do anything, `label` elements are already clickable. It just depends on what you want to do with that click

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Considering he wants to wrap it with `<a href="#faq"></a>` he seems to want it to work like an in-page anchor.

Comment: @connexo correct

Comment: If you want double purpose interaction elements, you'll have to resort to Javascript. And still I would consider that bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this code..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var $text = $('#nf-label-field-11').html();
    $('#nf-label-field-11').html('<a href="#faq">'+$text+'</a>');
});
```